# Place div below navigation bar

Tags: css, sails.js

I'm trying to place a Leaflet map inside a standard Sails.js view. Sails.js automatically adds a page header to every page. With fixed height, this is what the map looks like:

```
#mapid {
    height: 400px;
}
```

[image]

This isn't ideal because we want the height to be flexible depending on the screen size. With `absolute` position, the map fills the entire screen and hides the top bar.

```
#mapid {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

How can I make sure that the map fills the screen while keeping the top bar? I've tried setting the position to relative but that hides the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the 'top' value to the height of the topbar. For example:

```
#mapid {
    position: absolute;
    top: 56px; // Here
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Strangely, with that the map is once again taking up the entire viewport.

Comment: Did you mean to use `px`?